# Peg.js distinguish between missing values and white space

Tags: javascript, regex, peg

I have the following peg.js script:

```
start = name* 

name = '** name ' var ws 'var:' vr:var ws 'len:' n:num? ws 'label:' lb:label? 'type:' ws t:type? '**\n'
  {return {NAME: vr,
           LENGTH: n, 
           LABEL:lb,
           TYPE: t
  }}

type = 'CHAR'/'NUM'    
var = $([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)
label = p:labChar* { return p.join('')}
labChar = [^'"<>|\*\/]
ws = [\\t\\r ]
num  = n:[0-9]+ {return n.join('')}
```

to parse:

```
** name a1 var:a1 len:9 label:The is the label for a1 type:NUM **
** name a2 var:a2 len: label:The is the label for a2 type:CHAR **
** name a3 var:a3 len:67 label: type: **
```

and I'm encountering a couple of issues.

Firstly, within the text that I am parsing I expect certain value labels such as 'var:', 'len:', 'label:' & 'type:'. I would like to use these labels, as I know they're fixed, to delineate between the values.

Secondly, I need to allow for missing values.

Am I going about this the correct way?  Currently my script merges the value of the label with the type and then I get an error at :

```
Line 1, column 64: Expected "type:" or [^'"<>|*/] but "*" found.
```

Also, Can I do this with blocks of text too? I tried parsing :

```
** name a1 var:a1 len:9 label:The is the label for a1 type:NUM **
** name a2 var:a2 len: label:The is the label for a2 type:CHAR **

randomly created text ()= that I would like to keep

** name b1 var:b1 len:9 label:This is the label for b1 type:NUM **
** name b2 var:b2 len: label:This is the label for b2 type:CHAR **

more text
```

by amending the first line an adding the following:

```
start = (name/random)* 

random = r:.+ (!'** name')
    {return {RANDOM: r.join('')}}
```

I'm after a final result of:

```
[
   [{
      "NAME": "a1",
      "LENGTH": "9",
      "LABEL": "The is the label for a1",
      "TYPE": "NUM"
   },
   {
      "NAME": "a2",
      "LENGTH": null,
      "LABEL": "The is the label for a2",
      "TYPE": "CHAR"
   },
   {"RANDOM":"randomly created text ()= that I would like to keep"}]
[{
      "NAME": "b1",
      "LENGTH": "9",
      "LABEL": "This is the label for b1",
      "TYPE": "NUM"
   },
   {
      "NAME": "b2",
      "LENGTH": null,
      "LABEL": "This is the label for b2",
      "TYPE": "CHAR"
   },
   {"RANDOM":"more text "}]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want a negative lookahead `!(ws 'type:')` otherwise, the label rule will be too greedy and consume all the input to the end of the line.

As a side note, you can use the `$()` syntax to join the text of elements instead of `{return n.join('')}`.

```
start = name*

name = '** name ' var ws 'var:' vr:var ws 'len:' n:num? ws 'label:' lb:label? ws 'type:' t:type? ws '**' '\n'?
  {return {NAME: vr,
           LENGTH: n, 
           LABEL:lb,
           TYPE: t
  }}

var = $([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)

num  = $([0-9]+)

label = $((!(ws 'type:') [^'"<>|\*\/])*)

type = 'CHAR'/'NUM'

ws = [\\t\\r ]
```

Output:

```
[
   {
      "NAME": "a1",
      "LENGTH": "9",
      "LABEL": "The is the label for a1",
      "TYPE": "NUM"
   },
   {
      "NAME": "a2",
      "LENGTH": null,
      "LABEL": "The is the label for a2",
      "TYPE": "CHAR"
   },
   {
      "NAME": "a3",
      "LENGTH": "67",
      "LABEL": "",
      "TYPE": null
   }
]
```

Comment: This is a great help.  I don't know if this is a bit cheeky, but I've extended my question.  I think the issue is along the same lines, as it's about delimiting blocks of parsed code rather than text.

Comment: This almost works, but it doesn't concatenate the random text:      random = r:$(!('** name')(.))
    {return {RANDOM: r}}

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the following to work:

```
random = r: $(!('** name').)+ {return {"RANDOM": r}}
```

I'm not sure I completely understand the syntax, but it works.